# Can we use Github API to determine if a Github user is a bot?

Tags: api, github

As the title asks, I want to know how to determine if a Github user is a bot? The image below shows an example of a Github bot. Can we automatically identify them using the Github API? Or is there any other method?

[image: an example of GitHub bot]

Comment: Link us to a github bot please

Comment: @Worthy7, for example, the googlebot(https://github.com/googlebot), its user type is "User" in Github api. However, I found some other cases, e.g., welcome bot (https://api.github.com/users/welcome[bot]), its user type is "Bot". I don't know whether we can further search the bot users. It seems that Github only supports searching for regular users.

Comment: The thing is, we can just control github users by using the API. So there is no way to really know if a computer is controlling a user, or if a person is.

Answer (score 1):

When querying `https://api.github.com/users/{USERNAME}`, you'll get a JSON property called `type`. If the user is a bot, `type` equals the string `Bot`.

In my case, using Kotlin and the GitHub Java APIs, I've setup an extension function:

```kotlin
internal fun GHUser.isBot(): Boolean =
  type == "Bot"
```